# Trying to zoom a multilayer set of UIViews

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift3, uiscrollviewdelegate

Please point me in the right direction - I can find neither a solution nor a tutorial that solves my problem..

I have the following hierarchy of views in a ViewController:

```
UIView
  ScrollView
    Container
      Drawing
      Image
```

I can zoom in and out using a tap gesture, however, I don't want the pens in the drawing view to resize. I need to be able to draw lines on the image at a greater detail.

If I zoom the views separately, then the pens are out of sync with the image.

The views are setup in IB.
The code in ViewDidLoad to initialize things is as follows:

```
scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size

        scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
        scrollView.delegate = self
```

And the zoom method is:

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

I've tried starting the following alternatives:

```
scrollView.contentSize = drawingView.frame.size and
..
return drawingView
```

I've also set imageView as a subView of drawingView.
And finally, I've set both as subViews of the Container View (a UIView, not a UIContainerView.

I am conforming to the UIScrollViewDelegate.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You already indicated that you are using Swift in the tags. No need to put it in the title.

Comment: I may have a solution here: https://github.com/feialoh/FFImageDrawingTool